# spark 2.0 join - column resolution error

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to join 2 dataframes using the

```
def join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumns: Seq[String]): DataFrame
```

syntax. Both dataframes have the necessary join columns (say col1 and col2). However there is an error which says

```
'using columns ['col1,'col2] can not be resolved given input columns: [col1, col2, col3, ...]'
```

This same code worked in Spark 1.6.x. Anyone else face the issue? Help!!

**UPDATE**
More research led me to isolate the issue illustrated by following code. Its just sample code but my actual code follows the same pattern -

```
// reading from Hive .. the data is stored in Parquet format in Amazon S3
val d1 = spark.sql("select * from <hivetable> where companyid=3599")  
val df1 = d1.groupBy("companyid","loyaltycardnumber")
          .agg(avg("totalprice").as("avgtotalprice"))
val df2 = d1.groupBy("companyid","loyaltycardnumber")
          .agg(avg("itemcount").as("avgqty")) 
df1.join(df2, Seq("companyid","loyaltycardnumber")) gives error -
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: using columns ['companyid,'loyaltycardnumber] can 
not be resolved given input columns: [companyid, loyaltycardnumber, avgtotalprice, avgqty];
```

Reason why I need to split the initial DataFrame (d1) into multiple and then join them back is because there are a lot of complex calculations being performed on the two different subframes (df1 and df2)

**UPDATE**
More funkiness - if in the above code, I load the dataframe using spark.read.parquet() instead of spark.sql() .. the same code works.

Comment: Can you post your relevant code snippet?

Comment: just updated the comment and added some sample code ..

Comment: This doesn't look right. The line `d1.select("companyid","loyaltycardnumber").agg(avg("itemcount").as("avgqty")) ` should throw an exception even before the join. In it you're a creating a new dataframe of d1 by first selecting two columns and are then aggregating on 3rd column which you did not select. Spark should throw analysis exception complaining about this. Can you double check?

Comment: Sorry .. made a mistake typing in .. the select is actually a groupBy